# Jquery binding event on selected class

Tags: jquery, class, binding, events, selected

Is it achievable in jquery to bind an event to a group of control that has certain class? It seems to me, it can't. I google a bit and all that came up are nothing to do with events. Here's how my code looks -

```
$('.numonly').bind('keypress',function(event){
    if (event.which > 31 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code should work, here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/g3GsE/

Make sure that your code is wrapped like this so it doesn't execute until `document.ready`:

```
$(function() {
  $('.numonly').bind('keypress',function(event){
    if (event.which > 31 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) return false;
  });
});
```

Without this, it would execute immediately and the `class="numonly"` elements won't be there to find yet...the code needs to wait until document.ready so it fires after the elements are there, so the selector finds them.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the need to only bind events after the DOM has loaded

Answer (score 1):

Yes this code should work just fine. Just make sure you double check it on the server when submitted. So those who disabled JS can't get around your limitation.