# Why both onkeyup and keyup is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, dom

I want to display what the user is typing on the `<a>` Text from the input field. I already tried `.onkeyup` and `addEventListener` in javascript but they are not both working though it can detect the target input object but when it comes in `.onkeyup` and `addEventListener`it does nothing.

Here's what I am trying to do:

[image]

While a user is typing in the input field **First Name** it should be displayed in the `<a>` Hyperlink Text (Even the backspace key stroke should be applied)

Here's my snippet code in my view/blade template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo0">User Information</a></li>
    @for($guest_no = 1; $guest_no<=$guest_quantity; $guest_no++)
        <li>
            <a data-toggle="tab" 
                href="#guestInfo{{$guest_no}}" 
                id = "linkText">Guest #{{$guest_no}} //Target ID = linkText (this is where the changes will be applied)
            </a>
        </li>
    @endfor
</ul>
.......
<input id="passenger_f_name" type="text" 
class="form-control @error('passenger_f_name') is-invalid @enderror" 
placeholder = "First Name for Passenger #{{$tab}}" name="passenger_f_name"
value="{{ old('passenger_f_name') }}" required autocomplete="passenger_f_name" 
autofocus>
.......
<script type="application/javascript">

    var linkBox = document.getElementById('passenger_f_name');

    linkBox.onkeyup = function(){
        //alert("LOL"); //Used for checking if onkeyup is working properly = result: false
        document.getElementById('linkText').innerHTML = linkBox.value;
    }

</script>
```

I don't know why it is not working But I suspect [DOM]'s warning in console log (Posted screenshot instead of copying and pasting here because it does not have options in google chrome console to copy the warning message):

[image]

It has three inputs because every tab has a form and input on it that has same name and IDs (depends on the for loop's condition on how many forms would be generated).

P.S. I am using:

- Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- JQuery 3.4.1 & Bootstrap 3.4.1
- Laravel 6.0

Comment: use on input.....

Comment: If this has nothing to do with laravel, please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] WITHOUT PHP, Just HTML, CSS and Script

Comment: Try setting unique ids on each element

Comment: Change the `id=` to a `class=` and then read this SO post for binding events to all elements in the class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575420/jquery-binding-event-on-selected-class  ..... The error you show means that the `id=` is not unique (there are 3 of em) and so how can one be selected. You are already using jQuery so the link is relevant.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i tried but it still not working.

Comment: @GetSet I changed all id= to class= but still not working. Can I post the updated code?

Answer (score 0):

You need unique IDs

Here is how to do it if there is ONE input field and 3 guests

```js
$("#passenger_f_name").on("input",function() {
  $("li.active .linkText").text(this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo0">User Information</a></li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo{{$guest_no}}" class="linkText">Guest #1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo0">User Information</a></li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo{{$guest_no}}" class="linkText">Guest #2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo0">User Information</a></li>
  <li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#guestInfo{{$guest_no}}" class="linkText">Guest #3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<input id="passenger_f_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name for Passenger #{{$tab}}" name="passenger_f_name" value="" required autocomplete="passenger_f_name" autofocus>
```

Comment: It is still not working though I resolved all warnings and changed their ids... I also tried the code you provided in [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default an) and works with no problem. I even changed my external jquery and used the one in your snippet code (I used jquery 3.4.1). What might be the problem on my code?

Comment: I still haven’t seen a [mcve] of your tabs. Any console errors? It’s not a jquery version issue